# Why is mean ignoring trim parameter unless I use weird syntax?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to compute mean after dropping high and low values.  But the following ignores the trim parameter:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  summarize(mpg = mean(mpg),
            mpg_trimmed = mean(mpg, trim = 0.05))
#>        mpg mpg_trimmed
#> 1 20.09062    20.09062
```

But the following works:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  summarize(mpg = mean(.$mpg),
            mpg_trimmed = mean(.$mpg, trim = 0.05))
#>        mpg mpg_trimmed
#> 1 20.09062    19.95333
```

Why do I need to use `.$`?

Comment: Because you are _masking_ the original `mpg` (or creating a another in the scope of the function). Give a different name like `mpg_mean`. Remember that dplyr makes newly created variables immediately accessible.

Comment: @Edward, please post your comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are *masking* the original `mpg` variable (creating another in the scope of the function). Give a different name like `mpg_mean`. Remember that dplyr makes newly created variables immediately accessible.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  summarize(mpg_mean = mean(mpg),
            mpg_trimmed = mean(mpg, trim = 0.05))
#>   mpg_mean mpg_trimmed
#> 1 20.09062    19.95333
```

Comment: Three years later I still make this mistake some times...